# Will CSS media queries still affect hidden elements?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive

I'm working on a responsive design for a client. One way I do this is use CSS media queries.

Specifically the one I am working with:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 320px) 
  and (max-width: 991px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{
```

I have inside this query to make one of my elements 'float:none;'

```
#wp_checkout{float:none !important;}
```

Within my jQuery I execute responsive design:

```
if ($("#wp_checkout").css("float") == "none" ){


//code }
```

I'm having issues when I'm simply shrinking down the page in a "desktop" view (Chrome responsive development tools).. In "mobile" view everything is fine.

I believe I've diagnosed that the query isn't firing to make the element #wp_checkout{ float:none; }
[Here it shows float:left;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDvtK.png)

However this element is also display:none;
Can you still edit the DOM with media queries on elements that are hidden?

If you need any elaboration please let me know.

Comment: Does your "desktop" feature a pixel ratio of 2 or more?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes. I'm using the chrome development tool to display via "Desktop".. The ratio is set for 2 as default.